# Looking for a sci-fi comic anthology

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a particular issue of a sci-fi anthology magazine that came out in 1980/81. The art is in black and white.

I forget the name of the magazine, but one of the stories I remember. It had two astronauts traveling to a planet. The older one tells the story about how the planet they're going to is inhabited by all types of beautiful women, and the younger one listens.

When they get to the planet it's barren and empty. The younger guy gets mad, but the older guy states he told the lies because he didn't want the younger guy to go crazy with the long voyage. At the end, the younger guy relents and asks the older guy to tell more stories.

Comment: Possibly *Star Reach* magazine, though the last issue came out in 1979. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Reach

Comment: I did not find it on a quick flip through my *StarReach* collection – which, I now find, lacks #14 and #16–18.